# Grouped boxplots (3 per group) and 2 groups per xtick in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to make figure in this fashion but with bars replaced by boxplots:
https://i.postimg.cc/d1yRkJyf/SEM-images-Pore-count.jpg

I want each x tick to be associated with 2 groups (cross-, croiss+) of 3 boxplots(bot, mid, top)

I tried Seaborn to plot this graph. As of now, I figured out how to plot the conditions side by side in 2 plots:

```
import numpy as np
import spandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#-----------------------------IMPORT PORES DATA-------------------------------#

data = pd.read_excel('PoreData_Main_DF_complete.xlsx', engine= 'openpyxl')
data = data[['Area_of_pores', 'Position', 'Composition', 'Condition']]


#---------------------------------BOXPLOTS------------------------------------#

sns.catplot( x='Composition', y='Area_of_pores', hue = 'Position', col='Condition', data=data, kind='box', showfliers = False )
```

Obtained plot: https://i.postimg.cc/6qKZ8nw7/SEM-images-Pore-AREA.jpg

Example data here : https://usherbrooke-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/monv2802_usherbrooke_ca/Ed9_pRQ-jVJPs0CsFAsbtScBGgJ2OTeEgwPOa0v3lY6giw?e=lfeaxf

Comment: can you provide example data?

Comment: @ChrisSeeling example data is now available